# Change Hive Zookeeper port

Tags: hbase, hive, apache-zookeeper

I am trying to find a way to change the zookeeper port number in Hive but all of them are failure...
First I want to say is that my zookeeper for HBase cluster is running on port 2222, so I also want my hive's zookeeper port number to set to be 2222,  but it connects to port 2181 by default, like this:

```
2013-09-18 15:18:27,415 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn: 
Opening socket connection to server datanode2/192.168.1.97:2181. 
Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
```

So I change Hive's configure file (hive-default.xml.template) and also set

```
hive.zookeeper.client.port=2222
```

in hive;however, hive still connects to port 2181, the same log shows above...

Could anyone tell me how to change the zookeeper port number in hive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make that change in the **hive-site.xml** file. If it is not there create it manually. You **must not** touch the hive-default.xml file. Moreover the file where you have made the change is a template file.